# An interface with methods as type constraint for generic function

Tags: go, testing, generics, interface

I am trying to make use of generics when writing an asserting function for testing things however it gives me an error `Some does not implement TestUtilT (wrong type for method Equals...)` error. How can I make code bellow work if at all?

```
package test_util

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

type TestUtilT interface {
    Equals(TestUtilT) bool
    String() string
}

func Assert[U TestUtilT](t *testing.T, location string, must, is U) {
    if !is.Equals(must) {
        t.Fatalf("%s expected: %s got: %s\n",
            fmt.Sprintf("[%s]", location),
            must,
            is,
        )
    }
}

type Some struct {
}

func (s *Some) Equals(other Some) bool {
    return true
}

func (s *Some) String() string {
    return ""
}

func TestFunc(t *testing.T) {
    Assert[Some](t, "", Some{}, Some{}) 
    // Error: "Some does not implement TestUtilT (wrong type for method Equals...)"

}
```

Comment: `Some` doesn't implement `TestUtilT`, `*Some` does.

Comment: @JimB Is this what you mean? `Must[*Some](t, "", &Some{}, &Some{})` It doesn't work either. Error message is the same.

Comment: You also have the wrong signature for equals, `Equals(TestUtilT) bool` vs `Equals(other Some) bool`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```go
func (s *Some) Equals(other Some) bool {
```

with

```go
func (s *Some) Equals(other TestUtilT) bool {
```

Then replace

```go
Assert[Some](t, "", Some{}, Some{})
```

with

```go
Assert[Some](t, "", &Some{}, &Some{})
```

The first change will fix your initial error message, but your code will still not work without the second change as well.